# Menu button flows up and down while changing size of screen

Tags: animation, menu, menubar, bounce

I have a problem with my menu button.
It flows up and down while I change the size of my window. I didn't find the problem. But I know that it has something to do with my script file from the masonry. I have no clue where I could find this problem.
On [this page](http://immo17.com/primos.html) you will see the problem. Also it has a strange animation which I don't like (bounce down in the beginning)
Thanks for help.

Comment: Forgot something: HI GUYS!! :'D

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code and we'll help you solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) It's below.

Comment: BUMP, Still same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Immo17 | Primos</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="primos" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="francisco nobrega, immo17, madeira, haus in madeira, houses madeira, madeira projects, arquitectura, architekten, architecture, immobilien" />
  <meta name="author" content="Immo 17" />

  <!-- 
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 FREE HTML5 TEMPLATE 
 DESIGNED & DEVELOPED by FREEHTML5.CO
  
 Website:   http://freehtml5.co/
 Email:    info@freehtml5.co
 Twitter:   http://twitter.com/fh5co
 Facebook:   https://www.facebook.com/fh5co

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->

  <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />



  
  <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      
       <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/fresco.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
   <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/masonry.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
   <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/bootstrap.css.map" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
    <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/style.css.map" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
   <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/projects.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
   <link href="http://www.immo17.com/css/icomoon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
  
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fav.ico">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100|Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Animate.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- Flexslider  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/fresco.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/jquery_masonry_final.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/respond.min.js"></script>



<script src="http://www.immo17.com/js/main_masonry.js"></script>





  <!-- Modernizr JS -->
 
  <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->





  <!-- Lightbox -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fresco.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />



  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadUrl(newLocation) {
      window.location = newLocation;
    }
  </script>



  <style type="text/css">
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .container,
    .container2,
    .container3,
    .container24 {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding: 55px;
      /* padding-left: 40px; */
      /* padding-right: 40px; */
      /* padding-bottom: 40px; */
      background-color: white;
    }
    /*
.container:before, .container:after, .container24:before, .container24:after, .container2:before, .container2:after, .container3:before, .container3:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}


.container:after, .container24:after, .container2:after, .container3:after, .container3:after {
  clear: both;
}
*/
    
    .container3 {
      display: flex;
    }
    /*
@media (min-width: 1080px) {
 
  .container3 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    width: calc(0% + 450px);
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
  } 
  
  .container4 {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    margin-left: 32px;

    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  } 
    
}
*/
    
    @media (min-width: 1035px) {
      .demonstrations-media,
      .demonstrations-media_content {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .demonstrations-media_image {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2em;
        width: 450px;
      }
      .textcontainer {
        float: right;
        max-width: 520px;
        padding: 0px;
        /* border: 3px solid blue; */
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 1500px) {
      .demonstrations-media,
      .demonstrations-media_content {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .demonstrations-media_image {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2em;
        width: 600px;
      }
      .textcontainer {
        float: right;
        max-width: 620px;
        padding: 0px;
        /* border: 3px solid blue; */
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 1700px) {
      .demonstrations-media,
      .demonstrations-media_content {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .demonstrations-media_image {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2em;
        width: 500px;
      }
      .textcontainer {
        float: right;
        max-width: 820px;
        padding: 0px;
        /* border: 3px solid blue; */
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 1900px) {
      .demonstrations-media,
      .demonstrations-media_content {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .demonstrations-media_image {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2em;
        width: 600px;
      }
      .textcontainer {
        float: right;
        max-width: 820px;
        padding: 0px;
        /* border: 3px solid blue; */
      }
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-size: 32px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #000;
    }
    /*
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  
  .demonstrations-media_image_d {
    width:400px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  
  .demonstrations-media_image_d {
    width:600px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

*/
    /*
@media (min-width: 1360px) {
  .demonstrations-media,
  .demonstrations-media_content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .demonstrations-media_image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
  }
   .textcontainer {
    float: right;
    max-width: 420px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
  }
}
*/
    
    img.fr-content-element {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .fr-stroke-color {
      background: none;
    }
    
    .fr-window-skin-fresco .fr-content-background {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    .arrow {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 30px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -20px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
      background-size: contain;
    }
    /*
.fr-side-button-icon{

    cursor:  url(images/arrow_l.svg), pointer;

}
*/
    
    .fr-side-previous {
      cursor: url(images/Arrow/arrow-right-samplesL.svg), pointer;
    }
    
    .fr-side-next {
      cursor: url(images/Arrow/arrow-right-samplesR.svg), pointer;
    }
    
    .fr-position-outside .fr-position-text {
      text-shadow: none !important;
    }
    
    p.bold {
      font: bold !important;
    }
    
    u {
      text-decoration: none !important;
      border-bottom: 0.5px solid grey !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="fh5co-main-nav" role="navigation">
    <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle active"><i></i></a>
    <div class="js-fullheight fh5co-table">
      <div class="fh5co-table-cell js-fullheight">
        <ul>
          <li><a id="menu" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a id="menu" href="verkauf.html">Verkauf</a></li>
          <li><a id="menu" href="about.html">Team</a></li>
          <li><a id="menu" href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
          <a href="#">DE</a> |
          <a href="#">EN</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- menubar -->
  <div id="fh5co-page">
    <header>
      <div class="container2" style="padding-top: 40px;">
        <div class="fh5co-navbar-brand">
          <h1 class="text-left"><a class="fh5co-logo" href="home.html">Immo 17</a></h1>

          <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
        </div>
        <hr class="linesina">
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>

  <!-- Img Lightbox and Text floating solved-->
  </div>

  <div class="arrow">

  </div>


  <!-- Img Lightbox and Text -->

  <div class="container2">



    <div class="textcontainer " style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2 class="small-caps" style="background-color: #fff;">Fajã da Ovelha - Primos</h2>
      <p class="small-caps" style="background-color: #fff;">Wir verkaufen Land, bestehend aus zwei vereinigten Grundstücken mit wunderschöner Aussicht auf das Atlantische Meer. <br>Haben Sie hunger, jedoch keine Lust zum Kochen? <br>Dann haben Sie nur fünf Minuten weiter das schöne Restaurante o Principicio
        und keine zwei Minuten entfernt ein wunderschönes Café.<br> Die Grundstücke sind in Fajã da Ovelha, Madeira, Caminho das Irinhas.<br> <a href="https://www.google.ch/maps/place/32°46'49.2%22N+17°14'05.2%22W/@32.7803252,-17.2358588,503m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d32.780323!4d-17.234782">Hier</a>        finden Sie das schöne Gelände. <span style="font-size: 18px;">32°46'49.2"N 17°14'05.2"W</span>.<br> Die zwei Grundstücke können optional auch einzeln gekauft werden.</p>
      <p>Grundstücksfläche:&emsp;703m<sup>2</sup> <span>&emsp;(380m<sup>2</sup>&ensp;|&ensp;323m<sup>2 </sup>)</span></p>

      <p><b>Preis: 71'500 CHF</b><span style="font-size: 12px; padding-left: 7px;">65'000 Euro</span></p>
      <p><b><u>Kontaktpersonen </u></b><br>Christina Lüscher <span style="font-size: 12px; padding-left: 13px;"> DE | EN | IT </span>
        <br>Xavier Nóbrega <span style="font-size: 12px; padding-left: 30px;"> PT | EN </span></p>

    </div>



    <div class='demonstrations demonstrations-media animate-box'>

      <a href='images/Primos/primos1_1.jpg' class='fresco zoom' data-fresco-group='example'>
        <img src='images/Primos/primos1.jpg' alt='' class="demonstrations-media_image" style="margin-bottom: 55px; margin-top: 6px;}" />
      </a>

    </div>




    <div class="demonstrations demonstrations-media animate-box">

      <a href='images/Primos/primos2_1.jpg' class='fresco demonstrations-media_image' data-fresco-group='example'>
        <img src='images/Primos/primos2.jpg' alt='' style="margin-bottom: 55px;" />

      </a>

    </div>







    <div class="demonstrations demonstrations-media animate-box">


      <a href='images/Primos/primos3_1.jpg' class='fresco demonstrations-media_image' data-fresco-group='example'>
        <img src='images/Primos/primos3.jpg' alt='' style="margin-bottom: 55px;" />
      </a>

    </div>



    <div class="demonstrations demonstrations-media animate-box">

      <a href='images/Primos/primos4_1.jpg' class='fresco demonstrations-media_image' data-fresco-group='example'>
        <img src='images/Primos/primos4.jpg' alt='' style="margin-bottom: 55px;" />
      </a>

    </div>



    <div class="demonstrations demonstrations-media animate-box">

      <a href='images/Primos/primos6_1.jpg' class='fresco demonstrations-media_image' data-fresco-group='example'>
        <img src='images/Primos/primos6.jpg' alt='' style="margin-bottom: 55px;" />
      </a>

    </div>



    <div class="demonstrations demonstrations-media animate-box">

      <a href='images/Primos/primos7_1.jpg' class='fresco demonstrations-media_image' data-fresco-group='example'>
        <img src='images/Primos/primos7.jpg' alt='' style="margin-bottom: 55px;" />
      </a>

    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- load -->
  <script src='js/jquery_masonry_final.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main_masonry.js'></script>

  <!-- lightbox -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fresco.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Easing -->
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Waypoints -->
  <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Counters -->
  <script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
  <!-- Flexslider -->
  <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

  <!-- Main JS -->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```